# How to Create Bash Restart Script With Input

Tags: bash, shell, input

I want to create a restart script in bash so that when the process ends the process will be restarted.

I did it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx512M -jar Server.jar -o true
sleep 1
done
```

So far so good.
However, when the server ends I want to ask for an input (Y or N) if the server should even restart and if there is none within a few seconds the server should automatically restart, else the script should end.

Nevertheless, I am clueless how I should code this part.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true;do
  java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx512M -jar Server.jar -o true

  read -p "Do you wish to run it again (y/N)? " QUESTION
  
  case "${QUESTION}" in
    [Yy] ) 
      echo "Restarting process..."      
      ;;

    * ) 
      echo "Bye!"
      exit
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I don't know why but I get an error in line 8 which says: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in") although there is an in in this line

Comment: I tried it and it works, but tomorrow I will check it again and I will give you a feedback.

Comment: I just checked it, and it works for me on a different system. Which version of bash you are using? I edited it to enclose **${QUESTION}** by quotes, try it now on your system.

Comment: I fixed it and it now works. Thank you so much! However, do you know how to do the thing with the timeout so if I don't add an input it will automatically treat it as a "Y"?

Comment: No, the default is 'N'.